# How to read response headers with $resource?

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, response-headers

I'm using $resource to get data from my RESTful service and I need to read response headers to get 'X-Page' and 'X-Total-Pages' value for pagination.

**Example:**

```
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:2637
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 10 Apr 2014 16:53:01 GMT
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.1/2014-02-24)
Vary:Origin
X-Page:1
X-Per-Page:10
X-Total:17
X-Total-Pages:2
```

But I couldn't get full headers from server.

This is returned headers: 
[image]

This is the headers from server: 
[image]

This is my code:

```
.factory('TestAPI', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource("http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=showIP", {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET'
                }
            });
        }])

TestAPI.query({}, function (value, responseHeaders) {
                console.log(responseHeaders());
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
 });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your response headers you have to add the following header:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Total-Pages, X-Page
```

With this, the browser is capable to expose your customs headers an read it angular.

Comment: This saved my life! Thank you very much.

Comment: How yoy get that please helpp

Comment: I am unable to read X-AUTH-TOKEN from headers. Even  after adding  Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-AUTH-TOKEN